# Thymeleaf does not display Charts

Tags: javascript, chart.js, thymeleaf

I integrate Chart.js in my spring boot project . No charts displayed i do not the reason .

I added all the necessary js libraries  jquery, bootstrap also the css files of chart.js but nothing displayed and not error in the console .Any body had an idea about  the problem ?????

I think the problem that thymeleaf does not read the css file of chart.js included in the html page without knowing the reason why because i test this code in a standlone html page web outside of my spring project and it works fine .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
 layout:decorator="template">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<title>DOT</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../static/css/Chart.css" th:href="@{/css/Chart.css}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../static/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/myStyle.css"
 th:href="@{/css/myStyle.css}" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="../static/css/font-awesome.min.css"
 th:href="@{/css/font-awesome.min.css}" />






 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/html5shiv.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/respond.min.js}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/Chart.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/Chart.bundle.js}"></script>





</head>
<body>


 <div layout:fragment="content">

  <div class="container col-md-6">
   <canvas id="my" height="400" width="400"> </canvas>

  </div>

<script>

var ctx = document.getElementById('my').getContext('2d');
data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [10, 20, 30],
            backgroundColor:[ 'rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [ 'rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ]
    }],

    labels: [
        'Red',
        'Yellow',
        'Blue'
    ]
 
};

var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data
 
    
});

<script/>

</div>
</body>


 <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/html5shiv.min.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/respond.min.js}"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/Chart.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/Chart.bundle.js}"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: in your scripts. load jquery before bootstrap

Comment: same result i think  the div that contains the layout:fragment causes this miss function because when i remove it and the layout:decorator template the chart appears.